# SIGBUS on PCIe device behind a PCIe switch

Tags: linux, drivers, pci-e

I have a PCIe device connected to a PCIe switch, which is connected to the PCI bridge on my CPU.

Occasionally, I get a SIGBUS fault when communicating with the device, and my process crashes. The crash error says SIGBUS "While accessing address 0xdc631400".

In the crash dump, i check the process memory map, and at that address i have my PCI device mapped:

/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:04:00.0/resource2

So the question is, is it the PCI device that could be malfunctioning? Or is it the switch? Or is it the PCI bridge in my CPU?

The way I understand it, SIGBUS faults are asserted when the CPU physically cannot write to some memory address. T̶h̶e̶ ̶o̶n̶l̶y̶ ̶d̶e̶v̶i̶c̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶a̶c̶t̶u̶a̶l̶l̶y̶ ̶m̶a̶p̶p̶e̶d̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶o̶ ̶p̶h̶y̶s̶i̶c̶a̶l̶ ̶m̶e̶m̶o̶r̶y̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶m̶e̶m̶o̶r̶y̶ ̶m̶a̶p̶p̶e̶d̶ ̶I̶/̶O̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶m̶y̶ ̶C̶P̶U̶'̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶e̶g̶r̶a̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶P̶C̶I̶ ̶b̶r̶i̶d̶g̶e̶.̶ ̶N̶e̶i̶t̶h̶e̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶w̶i̶t̶c̶h̶ ̶n̶o̶r̶ ̶m̶y̶ ̶e̶n̶d̶p̶o̶i̶n̶t̶ ̶d̶e̶v̶i̶c̶e̶ ̶a̶r̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶n̶e̶c̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶a̶d̶d̶r̶e̶s̶s̶/̶d̶a̶t̶a̶ ̶b̶u̶s̶,̶ ̶s̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶y̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶c̶a̶u̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶ ̶S̶I̶G̶B̶U̶S̶.̶

EDIT: Scratch that. As I understand now, the (PCI) host bridge is actually the RAM controller itself, which is where all physical memory access is mapped to different devices (including RAM and PCI). So the host bridge itself doesn't have any physical address. So when accessing a physical address that isn't mapped to any device, the host bridge would let the CPU know, possibly triggering a SIGBUS fault?

Interestingly, according to /proc/iomem, my PCI devices are all mapped to their own physical memory, even if they're not directly connected to the host bridge, so the routing through various PCI buses to finally get to my target device must be something the pci host bridge takes care of, rather than some part of the kernel?

Comment: I most frequently see `SIGBUS` when performing an unaligned read or write on hardware that does not support it. Your address looks aligned. Maybe there is no memory backing the address. You will probably have to keep digging.